# iPhone gradient button issue

Tags: iphone, button, gradient

I have the following code to create gradient button:

```
CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradientLayer.frame = btnSignUp.layer.bounds;

gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.1f].CGColor,
                        (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.4f alpha:0.5f].CGColor,
                        nil];

gradientLayer.cornerRadius = btnSignUp.layer.cornerRadius;

[btnSignUp.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];
```

However, the bottom rounded corners are painted over too. I can't figure out why this happens. Any ideas?

Here is the picture: http://imageshack.us/a/img546/509/btnw.png

Comment: Have you verified that btnSignUp.layer.cornerRadius is a non-zero value?

Comment: That was it. Thank you, rmaddy.

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting iOS 5.0 or higher, you may want to create a PNG file of the gradient and stretch it to fill the button's background instead of messing with a layer.  I believe the performance impact of using a PNG is better.

So something like:

```
static UIEdgeInsets insets = {15, 15, 15, 15};  (or whatever your insets are)
UIImage* image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:insets];
[_button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is `_button.layer.masksToBounds = YES;`